# CSV data to array in scriptable object

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine

I am working on a quiz app. I have created a lot of questions and saved them as CSV files. My script fails when it gets to the line of taking the data from the CSV and entering the data into an array. My code is shown below. If I remove lines for the array answers[] then the code works correctly and creates 150 questions with no data for the answers[] array and correct data in all other fields. What am I doing wrong with the array?

```
public static void GenerateQuestions() //edit function name
{
    string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.dataPath + questionCSVPath);  //edit variable name

    foreach(string s in allLines)
    {
        string[] splitData = s.Split(',');

        QuestionCSV question = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<QuestionCSV>();  //no change to class unless different type of setup such as 2 or 3 stacked numbers
        question.ID = splitData[0];
        question.question = splitData[1];
        question.answers[0] = splitData[2];
        question.answers[1] = splitData[3];
        question.answers[2] = splitData[4];
        question.answers[3] = splitData[5];
        question.correctAnswer = splitData[6];
        question.solution = splitData[7];

        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(question, $"Assets/Resources/Questions/4thSub3/{question.ID}.asset");
    }

    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
}
```

The QuestionCSV script is:

```
public class QuestionCSV : ScriptableObject {
[SerializeField]
private string ID;
[SerializeField]
private string question;
[SerializeField]
private string[] answers;
[SerializeField]
private int correctAnswer;
[SerializeField]
private string solution;
```

What am I doing wrong with the array?

Comment: What is the exact error / wrong behavior you get? And could you include some example lines of your CSV file? And also the `QuestionCSV` class? Sounds like maybe you never create the array so it is `null` when trying to fill it with the answers?

Comment: After creating `question` instance, add `question.answers = new string[4];`

Comment: @derHugo ,thanks for the reply.  I have added the QuestionCSV class script to the question.  I get the error, "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: @RickDavin thanks for the reply. Do you mean that I should add question.answers = new string[4] after the line of code containing "CreateInstance" ?

Comment: @wrtuttle Yes, it could go there.  The point being that you must initialize `answers` with an array BEFORE you attempt to get data from `question.answers` otherwise `answers` is `null` which would throw a null reference exception on `question.answers[0]`.

Comment: @RickDavin it worked.  What a simple solution to take CSV data into an array.  I have another question.  I want to use the correctAnswer as an int instead of string.  The GenerateQuestions function is reading all CSV data as strings.  Is it better to convert the correctAnswer string into an int?  Is there a way to do it inside the foreach loop?  The data from the CSV for correctAnswer will always be 0, 1, 2, or 3.